# DLL vs WCF: Performance vs Extensibility (WCF just in case?)

Tags: wcf

Let's say you want to create an ASP.NET web app.  You *think* it will always just be a web app (with regular and mobile pages) but you never know.  It's possible someday you might want to have an iPhone, iPad, Android, or whatever app as a client.  If there is a 0% chance of this, you'd package your business layer as DLLs and reference them from your client.  If there's a 1% or greater chance of those other front-end apps in the future, you'd package your business layer in WCF and expose via http (i.e. service oriented architecture (SOA), software as a service that any client can consume regardless of platform).

- **DLL pro:** speed/performance.
- **DLL con:** Only Microsoft clients can consume and must have DLL with client.  That also means if DLL embedded with client app, then long distance to take data to business tier to process and then return.
- **WCF pro:** Extensibility.. any client can consume.
- **WCF con:** speed/performance.

Software architecture is all about finding the right balance of performance and flexibility.  I guess you'd have to go WCF in this case as an insurance policy?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to go with WCF.  If the need arises and you need to expose your BLL's functionality to other non-microsoft types, then you can create a new WCF service.  Inside this new service, you can create wrapper methods in your ServiceContract that expose your DLL's methods, etc.  So, you can just create your DLL and create a service for it in the future if a need arises.

Comment: That's what I thought would be the case.  But, when I played around with it.. you've got to jump through some hoops to wrap the DLLs in WCF.. much more cumbersome than just writing the business code directly in WCF.

Comment: Sure, you can't use the DLL as is.  You'll need to create wrapper methods that expose the DLL's functionality.  With this extra work you get the benefit of more flexibility, if that's what you want.

Comment: Sorry to still be confused.  

OPTION 1: Create DLLs and reference them in initial web apps. If an iPhone/Droid/whatever client app in the future, wrap the DLLs in WCF although cumbersome.  

OPTION 2: Create business code directly/natively in WCF and have initial web apps access via http.  Then, all in place for future client apps to do the same.

You'd prefer option 1?

Comment: Yes, Option 1.  All you'll need to do, if necessary in the future, is create a ServiceContract and have it's methods call your DLL.  With Option 2, you are introducing another layer/technology that may not be needed.  Why prematurely include WCF?  It's no big deal to add it later.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind you could use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) (or at least to add it to your list).
You can create web site that will call REST api and it will be available from native apps too.

Check next articles for more information:

- [Introduction to the ASP.NET Web API](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/05/introduction-to-the-asp-net-web-api.aspx)
- [ASP.NET WebAPI: Getting Started with MVC4 and WebAPI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC4-and-WebAP)

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind

- Define coarse-grained public methods in your BLL that are stateless.  If/when you wish to run as a WCF service you can easily wrap your library.
- Or implement as WCF and host locally

The second option is better suited for a proof-of-concept.  A good description is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx